# Running total in SQL with a reset condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, inventory-management

I have a data that combines inventory, sales forecast, and future supply data for different parts. I have combined it to give me a table that gives a net quantity each month for each part. See below:

| Date | Part | Net Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30/06/2021 | A | 1000 |
| 31/07/2021 | A | -150 |
| 31/08/2021 | A | -200 |
| 30/09/2021 | A | -500 |
| 31/10/2021 | A | -200 |
| 30/11/2021 | A | -200 |
| 31/12/2021 | A | 50 |
| 30/06/2021 | B | 100 |
| 31/07/2021 | B | -80 |
| 31/08/2021 | B | 20 |
| 30/09/2021 | B | -30 |
| 31/10/2021 | B | -35 |
| 30/11/2021 | B | -40 |
| 31/12/2021 | B | -150 |

I need to create a running total view that partitions by a part number and resets in the next month if it goes below 0. The starting point for the running total needs to be 0 if the previous month's closing inventory was negative.

My expected outcome is this:

| Date | Part | Net Quantity | Closing Inventory (Expected Outcome) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30/06/2021 | A | 1000 | 1000 |
| 31/07/2021 | A | -150 | 850 |
| 31/08/2021 | A | -200 | 650 |
| 30/09/2021 | A | -500 | 150 |
| 31/10/2021 | A | -200 | -50 |
| 30/11/2021 | A | -200 | -200 |
| 31/12/2021 | A | 50 | 50 |
| 30/06/2021 | B | 100 | 100 |
| 31/07/2021 | B | -80 | 20 |
| 31/08/2021 | B | 20 | 40 |
| 30/09/2021 | B | -30 | 10 |
| 31/10/2021 | B | -35 | -25 |
| 30/11/2021 | B | -40 | -40 |
| 31/12/2021 | B | -150 | -150 |

My current code is:

```
SELECT 
Date, 
Part, 
Net_Quantity, 
sum(Net_Quantity) over (partition by Part order by date) 'Closing_Inventory' 
FROM grouped
```

I am unsure how to make a condition based on the last value in the running total, the `lag` function is not able to view the previous row of the running total.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been easier if you had provided some sample data, but here is how I would solve this problem:

```
Declare @testData Table ([Date] date, Part char(1), NetQuantity int);
 Insert Into @testData ([Date], Part, NetQuantity)
 Values ('2021-06-30', 'A', 1000)
      , ('2021-07-31', 'A', -150)
      , ('2021-08-31', 'A', -200)
      , ('2021-09-30', 'A', -500)
      , ('2021-10-31', 'A', -200)
      , ('2021-11-30', 'A', -200)
      , ('2021-12-31', 'A',   50)
      , ('2021-06-30', 'B',  100)
      , ('2021-07-31', 'B',  -80)
      , ('2021-08-31', 'B',   20)
      , ('2021-09-30', 'B',  -30)
      , ('2021-10-31', 'B',  -35)
      , ('2021-11-30', 'B',  -40)
      , ('2021-12-31', 'B', -150);

   With runningTotal
     As (
 Select *
      , Inventory = sum(td.NetQuantity) over(Partition By td.Part Order By td.[Date])
   From @testData               td      
        )
 Select [Date]
      , Part
      , NetQuantity
      , ClosingInventory = iif(lag(Inventory, 1, 0) over(Partition By Part Order By [Date]) < 0, NetQuantity, Inventory)
   From runningTotal;
```

Comment: This gives different results than mine, but the difference doesn't show in the example data.

Comment: This does not return the right result. If it goes negative and then inventory comes in (so goes positive again) it will no longer return the right result it still takes the net inventory

Comment: Do you have examples where this doesn't work?  The results returned match your expected results - I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this...

```
--Add a column...
ALTER TABLE PartsInventory ADD RowNumWithinPart int;

--Assign row numbers partitioned by Part...
UPDATE PartsInventory
SET RowNumWithinPart = x.rownum
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Part ORDER BY [Date]) as rownum, *
    FROM PartsInventory
) x
WHERE x.Part = PartsInventory.Part AND x.Date = PartsInventory.Date

--Recursive CTE solution:
WITH InvTotalsCTE AS
(
    SELECT [Date], RowNumWithinPart, Part, Net_Quantity, Net_Quantity as Closing_Inventory
    FROM PartsInventory
    WHERE RowNumWithinPart = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Q.[Date], Q.RowNumWithinPart, Q.Part, Q.Net_Quantity, iif(P.Closing_Inventory < 0, 0, P.Closing_Inventory) + Q.Net_Quantity as Closing_Inventory
    FROM InvTotalsCTE as P
        JOIN PartsInventory Q ON (Q.RowNumWithinPart - 1) = P.RowNumWithinPart AND Q.Part = P.Part
)
SELECT [Date], Part, RowNumWithinPart, Net_Quantity, Closing_Inventory
FROM InvTotalsCTE
ORDER BY Part, RowNumWithinPart
```

Comment: I've been running this for over an hour and the query has not loaded - so I do not thing this solution (even if it works) is efficient enough for me to work with. I only have <10,000 records

Comment: Maybe you need an index. Is there an index on (Part, Date)?

Comment: I've tried your solution on a single part and it returned null for every result

Comment: I just noticed that my query is wrong. Let me try again...

Comment: Does this have to be a view? It would be simpler to break it into steps. Even if we can write it as a single query, the optimizer might not be able to make it efficient.

Comment: Ideally a view but absolutely not a requirement. If I output a table that is also fine